# Remove UITabbar upper border line

Tags: ios, border, line, uitabbar

I have been using UITabbar in an app.
There is an upper border line coming in top of the UITabbar.
Refer below image :-

I Googled it and tried the suggested code like :-

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Also

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:nil];

self.navigationController.toolbar.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

But none of them is working. Any solution?

[image]

Comment: **iOS 10.X** have some changes so please follow [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39858796/3752143).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
[self.tabBar setValue:@(YES) forKeyPath:@"_hidesShadow"];
```

or you can use

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentShadow.png"]];
```

or

```
 [[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:nil];
```

Comment: As you are adding background image also so just hide the shadow.

Comment: you mean i need a transparent image?

Comment: no need to add transparent image if you don't want any image for shadow at all. just pass nil. see my edited answer.

Comment: Awesome usama first line is working 

i.e [self.tabBar setValue:@(YES) forKeyPath:@"_hidesShadow"];

Comment: Be aware, the forKeyPath solution may cause a crash on 32 bit devices (at least using Swift). the imageNamed solution worked for me in Swift, but the last one did not.

Answer (score 25):

`tabBar.clipsToBounds = YES;` works for me.

Comment: really great! No need to do anything else - just single line. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 13):

Working solution with **iOS 13 & Swift 5**:

```
/** 
 * A custom subclass of `UITabBarController` to use whenever you want 
 * to hide the upper border of the `UITabBar`.
 */
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        // Removing the upper border of the UITabBar.
        // 
        // Note: Don't use `tabBar.clipsToBounds = true` if you want 
        // to add a custom shadow to the `tabBar`!
        // 
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            // iOS 13:
            let appearance = tabBar.standardAppearance
            appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            appearance.shadowImage = nil
            appearance.shadowColor = nil
            tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        } else {
            // iOS 12 and below:
            tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
            tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: @JsW are you doing some other additional adjustments to the UITabBar?

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me for iOS 11, XCode 9.4

```
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 5 Works for me

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        myTabBar.clipsToBounds = true


    }
```

Comment: do it in class UITabBarController

Answer (score 3):

Improving on one of the answers above - still a bit of a hack but works better. The answer above would hide the imageView with custom image.

```
    for tabBarSubview in self.tabBar.subviews {
        let tabBarSubviewName = String(describing: type(of: tabBarSubview))
        guard tabBarSubviewName == "_UIBarBackground" else { continue }
        tabBarSubview.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, This is called the perfect answer. Huge respect from me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add only this two line of code for remove border from your UITabbar:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

**UPDATE:** 
You canset background image as well and set shadow as a nil like following code

```
    UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: This works but i need to set background image also.
So if i remove first line then it shows the line

Comment: This is not working swift 3 xcode 8. How can I remove this line?

Answer (score 1):

`shadowImage` property of `UITabbar` is responsible for this border line (gray colored shadow) on `UITabbar`. Update value of this property to remove it.

Try this,
** Objective-C **

```
//Remove shadow image by assigning nil value.
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage: nil];

// or 

// Assing UIImage instance without image reference
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage: [[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

** Swift **

```
//Remove shadow image by assigning nil value.
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = nil

// or 

// Assing UIImage instance without image reference
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Here is apple guideline for [shadowImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623452-shadowimage)

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
open var shadowImage: UIImage?
```

> Default is nil. When non-nil, a custom shadow image to show instead of
>   the default shadow image. For a custom shadow to be shown, a custom
>   background image must also be set with -setBackgroundImage: (if the
>   default background image is used, the default shadow image will be
>   used).

Answer (score 1):

In our case, we needed an opaque tabBar with a subtle shadow above it without the border. This means `clipsToBounds = true` is off the table.

```
// ...somewhere in your AppDelegate class

let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.shadowColor = .clear // hides the top border

UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance

if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
  UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```

Min iOS Deployment: 14.0

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an answer without clipping to bounds. And the way using `UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage`
seems to be outdated

So I made a *not perfect* but working and safe solution to remove UITabBar shadow for iOS10 and iOS11 **without** clipping to bounds. Works on iPhone X too (would be strange if it did not ;) )

The code below runs through the `UITabBarController` hierarchy and looks for a shadow view. Which (for now) is `UIImageView` that is a subview of `_UIBarBackground`

```
extension UITabBarController {
    public func hideTopShadow() {
        // looking for tabBar
        for subview in self.view.subviews {
            let tabBarSubviewName = String(describing: type(of: subview))
            guard tabBarSubviewName == "UITabBar" else { continue }

            // looking for _UIBarBackground. The other subivews are UITabBarButtons
            for tabBarSubview in subview.subviews {
                let tabBarSubviewName = String(describing: type(of: tabBarSubview))
                guard tabBarSubviewName == "_UIBarBackground" else { continue }

                // looking for UIImageView. This is the only subview
                for shadowView in tabBarSubview.subviews where shadowView is UIImageView {
                    shadowView.isHidden = true
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        print(" **** ERROR: Could not find the shadow view \(self.self) \(#function)")
    }
}
```

Possible usage. I have a subclass of UITabBarController so I did following:

```
// to avoid excessive runs through the hierarchy after the shadow was hidden
fileprivate var hasHiddenShadow: Bool = false

override open func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    guard !hasHiddenShadow else { return }

    hasHiddenShadow = true
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
        self.hideTopShadow()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update your controller method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        self.tabBar.standardAppearance.shadowImage = nil
        self.tabBar.standardAppearance.shadowColor = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

worked for me