# Remove top line from TabBar

Tags: ios, ios10, tabbar

On iOS 10 this code doesn't work in order to remove the tabBar shadow line:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Somebody knows, what must I do to remove it?

On `iOS 9.3` with this two lines the line is removed, but `iOS 10` ignores `setShadowImage` command.

Comment: Can you show me graphically ?

Comment: The last line of the documentation for shadowImage says that if backgroundImage is nil then shadowImage is ignored and a default shadow is applied. So try removing the setBackgroundImage to see what happens.

Comment: The issue is that I need to set image to tabBar background...

Comment: @mitulmarsonia The screen capture from iOs 10 simulator http://i65.tinypic.com/24uw9vl.png

Answer (score 48, accepted):

removes the topline for @iOS 13.0

```
let appearance = tabBar.standardAppearance
appearance.shadowImage = nil
appearance.shadowColor = nil
tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
```

removes the topline for iOS 12.0 and earlier

```
tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS13 anymore! Have anyone tried? There's a new `tabBar.standardAppearance.shadowImage` but it doesn't work at all...

Comment: @SoftDesigner i have same problem, have you find any solution for iOS 13?

Comment: @YogendraPatel I'm using a custom shadow image which I'm adding to the tab bar directly: `tabBar.addSubview(shadowImageView)`. It overlaps the standard 1px line.

Comment: Updated the answer for iOS 13.0

Comment: appearance messes up unselected tab color

Answer (score 42):

Just try to bellow code for **iOS 10** :-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fondoTabBar"]];
    [UITabBar appearance].layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
    [UITabBar appearance].clipsToBounds = true;
    return YES;
}
```

**Swift 3.x**

```
UITabBar.appearance().layer.borderWidth = 0.0
UITabBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: This code is that I using until iOs 10. This code works on prior iOs 10 device, but on iOs 10 doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please try this demo its work for iOS 10 :- https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g4cpq282b7adyg0/AADk3jBHshvsQ-FNIWwzuOOZa?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for your sample code. This code works on iOs 10 but I need to change tabBar background, when I change background the line is show. This code is the same only I added a background image and you can see that the shadow image is shows on iOs 10, on iOs 9.3 works fine and the line is hidden.   https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlMk_BUOGnOImYtdCSCp6f1MGOu_AQ

Comment: @Camacho I have update my answer please review now your issue is fixed.

Comment: and thanks to Indian developer community, this isn't first time that you help me with an iOs question on stackoverflow, thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome :) Happy coding :)

Comment: Hi, is there any way to do this without getting rid of the tab bar's shadow as well? When I did this, it worked, but the tab bar's shadow also disappeared.

Comment: @EthanZhao Sorry i don't know other way.

Answer (score 9):

**Tested on iOS 14**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Remove default border line
    tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Working Solution as of iOS 13.3**

```
// remove top line
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    // ios 13.0 and above
    let appearance = tabBar.standardAppearance
    appearance.shadowImage = nil
    appearance.shadowColor = nil
    appearance.backgroundEffect = nil
    // need to set background because it is black in standardAppearance
    appearance.backgroundColor = .someColor
    tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
} else {
    // below ios 13.0
    let image = UIImage()
    tabBar.shadowImage = image
    tabBar.backgroundImage = image
    // background
    tabBar.backgroundColor = .someColor
}
```

Comment: This answer should be the correct one, because the answer marked as correct changes the color of the tabbar when applies the appearance.

Answer (score 8):

**For iOS 13**

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    UITabBarAppearance *appearance = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.standardAppearance copy];
    appearance.shadowImage = nil;
    appearance.shadowColor = nil;
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me @iso13:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
UITabBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = true
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = nil
```

or

```
UITabBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = true
UITabBar.appearance().layer.borderWidth = 0
```

or

```
UITabBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = true
UITabBar.appearance().layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
```

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 10 changed tabbar style to black did the trick

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.tabBarController.tabBar.barStyle = .Black
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way in your FirstViewController.swift:
**Swift 4.2**

```
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.50
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
```

Just change border color as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the following two methods at the same time:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a shadow image (property) of tabbar. Try following solutions and see.

Try this,
** Objective-C **

```
//Remove shadow image by assigning nil value.
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage: nil];

// or 

// Assing UIImage instance without image reference
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage: [[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

** Swift **

```
//Remove shadow image by assigning nil value.
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = nil

// or 

// Assing UIImage instance without image reference
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Here is apple guideline for [shadowImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623452-shadowimage).

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
open var shadowImage: UIImage?
```

> Default is nil. When non-nil, a custom shadow image to show instead of
>   the default shadow image. For a custom shadow to be shown, a custom
>   background image must also be set with -setBackgroundImage: (if the
>   default background image is used, the default shadow image will be
>   used).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to comment but to add to gnoix's answer, I had a slightly different problem in that I wanted the shadow *and* the background clear so I had in Swift

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let appearance = tabBar.standardAppearance.copy()
    appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
} else {
    tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let image = UIImage(ciImage: CIImage(color: CIColor.clear)).af_imageAspectScaled(toFit: tabBar.bounds.size)
    tabBar.backgroundImage = image
    tabBar.shadowImage = image
}
```

Comment: `appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()` works for me as I have shadow on tabBar layer as well.

Comment: Question is about removing just the topline of the tabbar and not about making tabbar background transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in ios 10. I fixed this issue just changing  the height of UITabBar (by default is 49). Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044218/change-uitabbar-height) how to change the height.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your own subclass of UITabBarController, you can set the
 values in viewDidLoad like this

**Swift 3**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0
        self.tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for me, the solution with tabBar appearance didn't work because it ignored my `tabBar.itemPositioning = .centered` in that case.

The thing that works for me is `tabBar.barStyle = .black`.

And don't forget to set `tabBar.backgroundColor = .white` or any other color your prefer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard thats an way
On tab bar controller, select the "tab bar"

[image: Like in this image]

and then add an runtime attribute "clipsToBounds" bool:

[image: like in this image]