# How to remove Tab Bar top border (shadow) in > iOS 10 and Swift 4 with a background image?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, swift4.1

I've been trying to remove the top border (shadow) line from Tab Bar in Swift 4 for > iOS 10. I'm also using a custom background image. I've just given up after searching for solutions, since none of them work.

The solution which came closest was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39850794/remove-top-line-from-tabbar/39858796).

The solution given everywhere works if there is no background or for < iOS 10. For iOS > 10 and using a custom background image none of solutions work.

I even tried using a transparent shadow image, but it required setting cliptobounds to true which doesn't show custom background image.

So at the end of all these solution I'm stuck. Couldn't find any working solution.

I'm setting these custom values in AppDelegate so that it works for all Tab Bars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just created a sample project using tab bar template from Xcode and write three lines of code

```
self.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0
self.tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
self.tabBar.backgroundColor = .blue
```

And tab bar top border is no longer visible. I've tested this on Simulator iphone 6 with ios 11.2

[image]

Comment: Humm!!! Weird I did try this solution before but didn't work. Now it works.

Comment: Thanks. I'm adding code in AppDelegate, following is the working code: UITabBar.appearance().layer.borderWidth = 0.0
UITabBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = true